# Switch workspace and move window shortcuts in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces, mate, ubuntu-mate

I recently installed the MATE desktop environment and set up the workspace shortcuts. I use Ctrl + Alt + Arrows to switch between workspaces, and Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Arrows to move a window to another workspace.

I'll try to explain my problem: let's say I'm in Workspace 1, and I have a window in Workspace 2, which I would like to move to Workspace 3. What I would like to do is to press Ctrl + Alt + Right to go from Workspace 1 to Workspace 2, and, just by additionally holding Shift and pressing Right, to move the window from Workspace 2 to Workspace 3. That is, without having to stop holding Ctrl + Alt in the process.

However, it seems that I do have to release Ctrl + Alt when I'm in Workspace 2, and then press Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Right to move the window to Workspace 3.

I hope I have explained myself. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? On my UM 16.04 LTS I can use  `<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<Shift>` to move active window across workspaces. I controlled the process by seeing changes on Workspace Switcher applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> you're switching between workspaces, and you don't select a workspace until you release, so you can't move a window by adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> because there are no windows in focus.

Comment: But it works as I say on other desktop environments such as Unity, KDE Plasma, Budgie...